# Get all orders count of a specific user programmatically

Tags: commerce

I want to get count of all the order placed by an user programmatically in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give count of completed orders placed by an user.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('commerce_order')
  ->condition('uid', $user_id)
  ->condition('state', 'completed')
  ->groupBy('uid')
  ->aggregate('order_id', 'COUNT')
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `->condition('state', 'completed')` to get all order placed by user.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('commerce_order')
  ->condition('uid', $user_id)
  ->groupBy('uid')
  ->aggregate('order_id', 'COUNT')
  ->execute();
```